# Can I split python dictionary values into separate dataframes with a dataframe name equal to the key name of the values it contains?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the dictionary `myDict`

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
        'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]}
data2 = {'Plant':['Cactus', 'Tree', 'Seaweed'],
        'Tastiness':[5, 3, 9]}

myDict = {}
myDict['df1'] = pd.DataFrame(data1)
myDict['df2'] = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Is there a way to split the dictionary in two dataframes and the dataframes would have the names `df1` and `df2`; i.e. names corresponding to the dictionary keys?

Comment: you can check `locals` but not recommended

Comment: This is a bad way to do things. Why do you need to do this? How would you then access those dataframes? Wouldn't using a dict be easier all-around?

Comment: The data frames I want to have are actually txt data files I read from a folder into a dictionary. I need to manipulate these data files (merge, add columns, ...). The names of the keys correspond to the names of the data files in the folder without the extension. This is important.